# Getting video as StorageFile

Tags: windows-phone-8, storagefile

I succeed in getting  Images as StroageFile with PhotoChooserTask. I have to do that know with video and song. The PhotoChooserTask cannot help. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no VideoChooserTask and no alternative.

A video is too big to be stored in the isolated storage or in the RAM, so choosertask is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your help but the boss don't understand the word impossible. I learned that there is a possibility by using native c++ code, have you any idea?

Comment: You can say that microsoft know this problem => https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1897833-video-chooser-task but i really don't know if it's possible to create native c++ code

Comment: The forum is very convenient. But I think that there is a solution which is using the windows phone 8.1 sdk. The FileOpenPicker was added  http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/16/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-contracts/